# How many positive, three digit integers contain atleast one 7?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**This is the Question:** How many positive, three digit integers contain atleast one 7?

For these kind of questions I have always followed a technique of first taking care of the restriction provided in the question. The Restriction is **contain atleast one 7**

**This is similar to the question:**

In how many ways can the five letters J,K,L,M,N can be arranged such that L is not in the middle. Well for this question,taking care of the restriction,  I know that the middle letter stage can be accomplished in **4** ways since it cannot contain L, so the combination is

$4\cdot3\cdot4\cdot2\cdot1 = 96$ ways.

But the above technique is not working for the question I asked. How to use the same technique where I first tackle with the restriction and then move on with the question.

**What I tried:**

Three Cases are possible:

1) Three Digits with atleast one seven: $1\cdot8\cdot7 = 56$ ways

2) Three Digits with atleast two seven: $1\cdot1\cdot8 = 8$ ways

3) Three Digits with atleast three seven: $1\cdot1\cdot1 = 1$ way

So, it should be **$56\cdot8 = 448$** ways but thats wrong, The answer is **252** ways

So, how can I solve this question with the same strategy that I have followed of taking care of the restrictions first?

Comment: Hint: try to find all 3-digit integers *without* $7$

Comment: yeah..thats what the second strategy is but I want to stick with one single strategy and master it which is taking care of that restriction first

Comment: Where does the $8$ in $56 \cdot 8$ come from? It is certainly not the number of permutations of three digits (with or without repetitions). If anything, brute-forcing a solution this way is a good advertisement for using the sort of strategy Michael suggested for this sort of problem in general.

Comment: @Travis: I thought multiplying the number of ways in my first case with the second case will be the answer. so thats where 56*8 comes from?

Comment: @Travis: Then how ccome the strategy works for that `alphabets` question that I have posted and does not work for this one? I mean there should be some way right? with the same strategy?

Comment: This is a GRE question and I am really lost

Comment: What about other number, they can also repeat?

Comment: @Chiranjeev:  yeah..they can repeat, okay..now I get it after the question that u have asked, I guess my first case is itself wrong, as there can be 1*8*7 and 1*8*8 ways as well. Am I making any sense?

Comment: So why you did $1\times 8\times 7$, this should be $1\times 8\times 8$, other thing is why you leaving $0$, it can come at unit and 10th place

Comment: @IdentityUnkn0wn I'm not sure which other question you mean; perhaps you could include a link here. Given three distinct digits $7, a, b$, there are $6$ possible ways in which these can be ordered, leading to $6 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$ numbers with three distinct digits, but we must subtract from this count the numbers with leading zero(s). Similarly, given a digit $a$ not $7$, there are three numbers with the digits $7, a, a$, but again, we must subtract the numbers with leading zero(s).

Comment: @Travis: http://www.greenlighttestprep.com/module/gre-counting Please checkout the 11th question and 12th question, they have solved the 11th question with both strategies but the 12th question with just one strategy, hope this will help you in understanding what I am trying to convey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the analogy with the permutations of letters is making this problem more complicated than it needs to be.

Using the restriction that the number has *at least* one seven, you can first find the numbers that have exactly one $7$, then the numbers that have two $7$s, and then the number that has three $7$s and then add the results.

To find the number of numbers, think of choosing a digit for each spot: _ _ _

For **one seven**, you can fix a $7$ in a spot, say the first one, so the number looks like 7_ _ and note that for the other spots you can have any of the other 9 digits ($0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,$ or $9$), so there are $9\cdot 9=81$ such numbers.

For numbers of the forms  _ 7 _ and _ _ 7 the count is different because the first digit cannot be $0$, so there are $8\cdot 9=72$ possibilities for each.

Thus, in total there are $72+72+81=225$ three-digit positive integers with one seven as a digit.

**Two sevens**: For the form _77 there are 8 possibilities because the first spot cannot be 0, and for each of the forms 7_7 and _ _7 there are 9 possibilities, so in total there are $8+9+9=26$ three-digit positive integers with one seven as a digit.

**Three sevens**: There is only one, $777$.

So in total there are $225+26+1=252$ three-digit integers with a seven as a digit.

Comment: thank you so much man..Thats what I was asking, yeah the analogy with that letters question made it harder for me

Answer (score 3):

A simple way.

1. The first digit is 7. There are 100 of such numbers.
2. The first digit is  not 7 but the second is. There are $8\cdot10=80$ such numbers.
3. The first and second digit are not 7 andthe last one is 7. There are $8\cdot9=72$ (the first must be nonzero) such numbers, which gives the desired 252.